# how to add lzw_decode from imagecodecs at pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I need to transfer my main.py file to .exe and I made that

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree._utils" main.py
```

but I got this Error could not import the name 'lzw_decode' from 'imagecodecs'

Comment: Try to add the `imagecodecs._shared` and `imagecodecs._imcd` modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to answer but I faced the same issue with my code.
From this link: https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/issues/34, i understand it may be a version issue. One potential solution could be to upgrade to a later version of Python.
Another solution (at least it worked for me) was to add the imagecodecs._shared and imagecodecs._imcd modules with
--hidden-import during compilation